# How to use Weighted Allocation using MDX in Excel based on Previous Year Values? (Writeback in SSAS)

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

Currently I build up an Excel sheet for capacity planning in our department. 
In Excel I get the data from a cube (SSAS multidimensional) with activated Writeback on my planned fact table.

I have two fact tables: "Beleganzahl IST" (number of vouchers, actual status) and "Beleganzahl PLAN" (planned status). The third column ("Vergleich Vorjahr") is a calculated member which shows me the value compared to the previous year/month/calendar week/day (depending on the date dimension hierarchy level).  At the moment the planned status is equal to the actual status.

This is how it looks like:

[Excel Capacity Planning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz7NT.png)

My What-If Analysis Settings in Excel are "Increment based on old value" and "Weighted Allocation". I'm trying to come up with an MDX expression in Excel that allocate my input weighted when the former value was 0. For example: When I replace the 0 with 2000 in "Beleganzahl PLAN" for week number 30 (2018), the MDX expression should provide a weighted allocation based on cw 30 in 2017.

I tried below MDX code, but Excel calculates six-digit and partly negative numbers.

```
IIF((([Dim Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Beleganzahl PLAN])=0,
                (ParallelPeriod(
                 [Dim Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],
                    1,
                    [Dim Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Beleganzahl PLAN]
                    ),
    [Measures].[Beleganzahl PLAN]
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.